# What might cause IE8 to show phishing warning page?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, phishing

We have a situation where we took a client site online and for some reason, IE8 shows the bright red phishing page when you go to the site.

We have our normal Google Analytics code at the bottom of the page but we are also trying to track a poll in the middle of the page using Google Analytics. We're not sure if this might be the cause?

The other thing, which might be closer to the answer is that we had set the test site up on a sub domain on our own server when the client was doing QA testing before it went live.

Could this have been the cause for IE to pick up that it might be a phishing site?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to the [IE  phishing filter FAQ page](https://phishingfilter.microsoft.com/PhishingFilterFaq.aspx):

> Q. What does it mean when a Web site
> is blocked and flagged in red as a
> reported phishing Web site?
>
> A. A
> reported phishing Web site has been
> confirmed by reputable sources as
> fraudulent and has been reported to
> Microsoft. We recommend you do not
> give any information to such Web
> sites.

Your concern about the subdomain should not produce anything more than a yellow bar warning - if it has not been reported before:

> Q. What does it mean when a Web site
> is flagged yellow and "suspicious"?
>
> A.
> A suspicious Web site has some of the
> typical characteristics of phishing
> Web sites, but it is not on the list
> of reported phishing Web sites. The
> Web site might be legitimate, but you
> should be cautious about entering any
> personal or financial information
> unless you are certain that the site
> is trustworthy.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me amelvin. We've managed to get in contact with MS and will see if they can unblock us. :)